# alpine.js data() x-data directive

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm using alpine.js v3 with some modules for the data

```js
import Foo from './foo';
import Bar from './bar';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

window.Alpine.data('data',  () => ({
    foo: Foo(),
    bar: Bar(),
}));

window.Alpine.start();
```

```html
<body x-data="data">
```

Whenever I try to access the data
`<button @click="data.foo.doSomething()">`
I get the error

> Alpine Expression Error: data is not defined

Do I have to add it with the `x-data` directive anyways?

---

*(update)*

And how can I access this data from another component, e.g.
Get `status` of the `Foo` component and call a method of `Bar`:

```js
window.Alpine.bind('SomeButton', (name) => ({
    'x-init'(){
        const data = window.Alpine.$data;
            
        if(data.foo.status === 'open'){
            data.bar.doSomething();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`Alpine.data()`](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data) you define a component. After that you can access directly all of the properties of the component inside the element where you applied it via `x-data`. Here `data` is the component, so you don't have to prefix its properties with `data.`:

```
<div x-data="data">
  <button @click="foo.doSomething()">Call doSomething()</button>
</div>
```

Answering your second question: since you have one "global" component that you applied to the topmost element (`body`), each child component can access the properties of this parent component. So inside `SomeButton` "bind-object"-type component, we can access them in the component's definition using the `this.` prefix.

```
window.Alpine.bind('SomeButton', () => ({
    '@click'() {
        if (this.foo.status === 'open') {
            this.bar.doSomething()
        }
    }
})
```

Here we attached our logic to the click-event: we call `bar.doSomething()` if the status is 'open'.

```
<div x-data="data">
    <button x-bind="SomeButton">Call bar.doSomething() if status is 'open'</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I got it now. I've updtated my question with another one, maybe you have an answer to that as well.

Comment: @Alex I've answered that as well.

Comment: oh, it's that easy :) thanks alot!